# labeling the points in a map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

Is there any code to label the point data that are displayed over the map.I have totally 600 points on my map.I want to name it with numbers from 1 to 600.So that user can easily identify the points using the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible in Fusion Tables.  An issue has [been created](http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=223) to request this.  At the bottom of that issue's posts there is a message implying that it can be done now using the  Trusted Tester API. There is an example mouse-over posted.

Answer (score 0):

This page might be able to help you out: [dynamic icons for google maps](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons)
It shows how to use dynamic markers for your Google Maps.

Comment: I have a column in my FT called House ID.All those Id should be displayed over the map as label.???

Comment: do `for($i=0;$i<600;$i++){chst=d_map_spin
chld=2.1|0|FFFF42|13|b|houseNumbers[$i]` and add it to the map every time.

Comment: Actually all my points are of type Location.So i have used configure styles in Fusion table to map it.How to pin?